# Tablelayout as the number of columns increase the space between them decreases1

Tags: android, tablelayout, spacing

I am adding columns to a tablelayout dynamically. My table has 4 columns. The number of rows are dynamic in nature. I tried ti have a proper display for my tablelayout and tried almost all permutations and combinations but I the problem persists.

The space between the first and second column is more than space between 2nd and 3rd column is more than 3rd and 4th column.

I tried shrink columns, stretch columns and many other solution.

Answer (score 0):

A `TableLayout` is not actually a table as you think. It is just a two dimensional layout.

Use a `ListView` where all columns are of the same dimensions. You can define custom columns for your data. 
I recommend reading a `ListView` tutorial like this: http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: Thanks for the information. I hope it will help me solve my problem.